# How can I use TPL with the new APIs in Azure StorageClient 2.0 and newer?

Tags: azure, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5, azure-table-storage, azure-blob-storage

The Azure Storage client was recently updated to version 2.0, and I haven't found any API that returns Task.

How can I use TPL with Table Storage?  .. Blob or Queue?

For your reference the new API has an [example here for Table Storage.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dmetzgar/archive/2012/11/02/upgrading-table-storage-code-to-azure-sdk-1-8.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Looking through some of the source under https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-net/ it appears that they haven't had a chance to add the Task versions yet (seems odd since it specifically mentions targeting .NET 4), but the operations appear to have the Begin* and End* versions available, so you could use [the FromAsync method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync.aspx) to wrap each pair in a task for easier consumption.

Does seem like an odd omission AFAICT, though.

Comment: I use TPL fine right now with the new libraries.  It is actually easier, since the new 2.0 storage libraries are synchronous wrappers around the REST API, before it was a mess using the APM model with waits/resets etc.